# MIKROTIK - set proxy authentication

Tags: proxy, mikrotik, routeros

Is it possible to set mikrotik authetication to be used for set the connection of other applications to internet using mikrotik proxy?

For example connect miranda IM using mikrotik proxy server:

[image]

[image]

I've tried to use hotspot login, bypass hotspot for selected MAC/IP (IP Bindings rule and and login without credentials), but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Here is the [wiki](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/Proxy) link, nowhere is authentication mentioned.

MikroTik used to have a Socks proxy, but even that didn't support authentication.

EDIT:

I e-mailed MikroTik support (support at mikrotik.com) to double check my info and got a reply from @Sergejs. The answer is definitely no. The [Socks](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/SOCKS) proxy still exists, but this also does not support authentication.

Comment: Which is probably why I see lots of malicious traffic coming from MikroTik proxies. [It's apparently open by default.](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/How_to_Block_Websites_%26_Stop_Downloading_Using_Proxy)

Comment: MikroTik is very powerful, sometimes a bit too powerful. One would except to have firewall rules in place to only allow access to port 8080 or 3128 or whatever, just like one should have firewall rules in place to protect SMTP port 25 (to avoid open mail relays)!